# Javascript: reverse an array of document.getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript

i have this variable that is:

```
var stars = this.parentNode.children
```

and its value is:

```
[span.rate, span.rate, span.rate.rated, span.rate.rated, span.rate.rated]
```

Now i want to reverse it, but if i try:

```
stars.reverse()
```

I obtain

```
Uncaught TypeError: stars.reverse is not a functionupdateRateStar @ app.js:75(anonymous function) @ app.js:98
```

I cannot understand why it works with an array like:

```
[1,2,3]
```

So if i try:

```
[1,2,3].reverse()
```

it works. Thus i cannot understand the problem

Comment: Because `this.parentNode.children` is not an array. [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: No need to call slice first: `let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]; let reversedArray = [].reverse.call(arr, arr); console.log(reversedArray) // [4, 3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call `Array.prototype.reverse` on `NodeListCollection`. Instead, you should use:

```
var stars = [].slice.call(stars, 0).reverse()
```

Comment: Why can you call forEach on nodeList but not reverse?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
var revArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply( a ).reverse()
```

The reason is that you have a NodeList and not an Array there. Both behave similarly in many cases, but the NodeList does not have the array methods.

With the

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply( a )
```

part, we convert the NodeList to an array, which can than be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a NodeList, which doesn't have a reverse. You can tell an object's prototype (like class in other languages) using:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(stars)
```

Which returns `[object NodeList]`. An array would return `[object Array]`.

**If you own the prototypes** (ie, this isn't a library), you can run:

```
NodeList.prototype.reverse = Array.prototype.reverse
```

then

```
stars.reverse()
```

Will work. Which is a lot more logical and pleasant to look at than constantly borrowing the method off Array.

Again, **you own the prototypes here, be aware that it's on you to fix if the browser adds a prototype in future.** You may prefer:

```
NodeList.prototype.sirkoReverse = Array.prototype.reverse
```

Which still reads nicely but is less likely to have conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It has different type , like **NodeList** and **Array**.

I suggest you to use this function:

```
var reverse = function(arr) {
   var result = [];
   for (var i = arr.length - 1;i !== 0;i--) {
       result.push(arr[i]);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Second variation:

```
function xorSwapHalf(array)
{
    var i = null;
    var r = null;
    var length = array.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i += 1)
    {
        r = length - 1 - i;
        var left = array[i];
        var right = array[r];
        left ^= right;
        right ^= left;
        left ^= right;
        array[i] = left;
        array[r] = right;
    }
    return array;
}
```

There is another swap method called **destructuring** assignment: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring

Destructuring assignment:

```
function destructuringSwap(array)
{
    var left = null;
    var right = null;
    var length = array.length;
    for (left = 0, right = length - 1; left < right; left += 1, right -= 1)
    {
        [array[left], array[right]] = [array[right], array[left]];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Using `ii = arr.length` in your first example is pointless. You're not using the array length in each loop, so there's no need to cache it.